# Discordpy member history() function returning nothing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to get my own message history using the `member.history()` method. But all i get is an empty `asyncIterator` that doesn't have anything in it.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".",intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    me = ctx.guild.get_member_named("Slade")
    print(me)
    async for message in me.history(limit=5):
        print(message)

client.run("token would go here")
```

The only thing the code above prints is the ready message and my own discord name and tag.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you executing your command in a guild that has history for the member named `Slade`. Your code works for me just changing the member name to a member in one of my guilds?

Comment: Yes. Im going off the `ctx.guild` argument which is directly pointing to the guild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem. For some reason both `member.history()` and `user.history()` function return **private DM's with the bot** not the guild message history.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
messages = await channel.history(limit=5).flatten()
```

this  will return a list of messages.

So your function will be:

````
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    me = ctx.guild.get_member_named("Slade")
    print(me)
    messages = []
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        message = await channel.history(limit=5).flatten()
        messages.append(message)
    for message in messages:
        print(message[0].content)
    ```

This returns for you 5 messages of every channel in your server.
````

Comment: This only works partially. I need to return a members history, not channel's. And this also returns an empty list.

Comment: Check now please.

Comment: The updated answer unfortunetly wouldn't even compile, since you're referencing a property that doesn't exist - `ctx.author.channel`. And if we left out the `.author` part, it would still not do what i need. As i said previously, i need to return a member's chat history, not a channel's chat history.